# How to open a new window with a view in xPages and define the size of the new window

Tags: xpages

I have a button on an xpage that I would like to open a popup/small new window that displays a view.  How do I code the new window and specify the size of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Extension Library's `Dialog` control.

Define your dialog box with

```xml
        <xe:dialog id="dialog1">
            <xe:dialogContent>
               ... your view control ...
            </xe:dialogContent>
        </xe:dialog>
```

and open it with

```xml
        <xp:button value="Show Dialog" id="button1">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                     XSP.openDialog("#{id:dialog1}");
                ]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
```

Good examples are Core_Dialog.xsp and Core_InPlaceDialog.xsp in database "XPages Extension Library Demo" which is included in [OpenNTF's XPage Extension Library Download](https://extlib.openntf.org/).

The size of the dialog box is calculated automatically depending on content. If you want to set size explicitly then use the style property with width and height:

```xml
        <xe:dialog id="dialog1" style="width:1000px">
            <xe:dialogContent style="height:700px">
```